# Execute command after successful login as Root

Tags: bash, ssh, centos

I want execute a command after someone successful login as Root user, its common to send email to admin about this but i want to execute my command instead of send an email to admin.

I’ve added my rule into `/root/.bashrc`:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
MYCOMMAND
```

The command runs without problem but it notify in SSH that MYCOMMAND run.

I don’t want to have this notification when login to SSH. How can I only run the command when it is needed and not when I login as root?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change your dot file to something like:

```
if [ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ] && [ -z "$SSH_TTY" ]
then
MYCOMMAND
fi
```

The idea is in SSH session these variables are set.

Comment: This conditional statement is unable to perform the task. No operation occurs after entering the server

Comment: “This conditional statement is unable to perform the task.” Then why did you check this off as the answer that solved your problem?